# Setting javascript Image with S3 CORS seldom working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, amazon-s3

I'm trying to work with the canvas element to save some images. I noticed I was having problems in chrome and isolated the issue down to setting the initial image.

```
<a href="#" data-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imphotos/uploads/thumb_IM_17592186048618_17592186048643.jpg">ONE</a>
<a href="#" data-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imphotos/uploads/thumb_IM_17592186047657_17592186047769.jpg">TWO</a>
<a href="#" data-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imphotos/uploads/thumb_IM_17592186047657_17592186047727.jpg">THREE</a>

  var setImg = function(src){
    var img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.onload = function(){
      alert("LOADED!");
    }
    img.onerror = function(){
      alert("ERROR!");
    }
    img.src = src;
  };

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
      var src = $(e.currentTarget).data('src');
      setImg(src);

    });
  });
```

The first time I do this, it works fine, but every subsequent request to build a second / third image fails supposedly due to CORS settings, but here are my CORS settings:

```
<CORSRule>  
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
```

After a click handler which builds a new image, I get the error:

> Image from origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

But not initially, so I'm so confused. And it works in Firefox.

EDIT:

After more debugging, I realized the first / subsequent image thing was just chance... It had nothing to do with the order of the load.

I made this JS fiddle, it's just that SOME pics in my S3 bucket are working with this method and others are not. Do I need to retroactively apply CORS settings to pics in buckets? Is this an S3 bug? Is there something wrong with my images?

If you click on "TWO" you will see an alert indicating loading, 1/3 both error out and give the CORS message in the console.

https://jsfiddle.net/6L44ttus/

Edit 2:

Having read that perhaps I need to switch my bucket name to the front (e.g. my-bucket.s3 instead of s3.my-bucket, I tried that to no avail. Now none of the images work:

https://jsfiddle.net/6L44ttus/3/

Comment: is this related documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: I'm following that. I should mention this happens before I even use the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem... 
I'm loading the images from my localhost http and was pulling assets from https...

EDIT* Actually this isn't the answer at all.

Had some false positive. I ended up setting up an nginx proxy with the right headers.

Comment: May be it's AllowedHeader issue in Amazon S3 CORS configuration as I mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282242/cross-origin-issue-occuring-while-converting-amazon-s3-images-in-div-to-canvas